How do i straighten out the UV islands without causing them to stretch?
I'm still farily new to UV editing in blender, so i'm sorry if i'm asking a question with an obvious answer.
I modeled a custom shape for a knob that's supposed to be on top of a temple. There's only one problem, some of the faces become rotated while others are displaying the checkered texture as straight and aligned. I tried to fix this by straightening the curved UV islands that the knob has, however that in turn led to the faces becoming stretched (and light blue since i've activated the "show stretching option").
Is there any way to straighten out the UV islands that belongs to the knob without causing them to stretch?
Also, how would you place the seams on my model?
Picture of the curved island before straightening it out with "follow active quads":

Picture of the same island after straightening it out:

Picture of my seam placement and my "knob-object":


Take a step back.... how do you imagine a grid texture matching a cone? Is it possible at all? I don't think so. You better try with a proper texture and accept the deformations.
